# Ntp server not responding to my client

Tags: c, sockets, ntp

I have written a really small ntp client, but after sending the packet I do not receive a response from the server, which I have confirmed with tcpdump.

I have defined a struct, which is used to transfer the ntp packets.

```
struct NtpMessage_t {
    unsigned int first_line;
    unsigned int root_delay;
    unsigned int root_dispertion;
    unsigned int ref_id;
    unsigned long long ref_timestamp;
    unsigned long long origin_timestamp;
    unsigned long long receive_timestamp;
    unsigned long long transmit_timestamp;
};
```

After filling the packet with `message->first_line = 0b00100011000000000000000000000000;` I send the packet to `de.ntp.pool.org` but I do not get a response back. The socket initialisation and the sending and receiving of messages is done with the following code:

```
for (i = result; i != NULL; i = i->ai_next) {
    cfd = socket(i->ai_family, i->ai_socktype, i->ai_protocol);

    if (cfd != -1) 
        break;
}

if (i == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

NtpMessage *message = calloc(1, sizeof(NtpMessage));
message->first_line = 0b00100011000000000000000000000000;
if (sendto(cfd, message, sizeof(NtpMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *) i->ai_addr, i->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    printf("Send failure: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (recvfrom(cfd, message, sizeof(NtpMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from_addr, &from_addr_len) < 0) {
    printf("Receive failure: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Tcpdump gives me the following output, from which I understand that my message is getting sent correctly but no answer is being received:

```
MY_IP_ADDR.50318 > 64.99.80.121.123: [udp sum ok] NTPv0, length 48
unspecified, Leap indicator:  (0), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 0 (1s), precision 35
Root Delay: 0.000000, Root dispersion: 0.000000, Reference-ID: (unspec)
  Reference Timestamp:  0.000000000
  Originator Timestamp: 0.000000000
  Receive Timestamp:    0.000000000
  Transmit Timestamp:   0.000000000
    Originator - Receive Timestamp:  0.000000000
    Originator - Transmit Timestamp: 0.000000000
```

Since there is no message in the other direction, it means that there is no response, if I am not mistaken. Is it so and if yes, what goes wrong here? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you really send the datagram to `de.ntp.pool.org` ?  If so, try sending it to `de.pool.ntp.org` instead.  But if you're going to send a lot of these datagrams you should find a more local NTP server (or set up your own) instead of pestering the pool servers. As far as the datagram itself goes, you have an illegal value in the precision field.  Also, it's not a good idea to send C structures directly on the wire; the compiler may insert padding between members and the endianness of multibyte fields may be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried lots of ntp servers but no one worked. Secondly, if I don't send the structure itself then how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have many, many reasons for the server not to emit a response to your ntp packet.  I see several things you have deliverately hidden in your example, so most probably the problem is ignorance of the NTP protocol specification.

How do you fill the packet contents?  Have you checked for compiler spare bytes to fill the holes for structure alignment?  Have you taken into account that, in NTP protocol all short, int, and 64bit timestamps have to be in network byte order (most significant byte first) ????

Finally, NTP servers act on incorrect input by just ignoring the incoming packet, but you assume the packet is correct.